# Sending image in base64 to Java webserver, convert and save it

Tags: java, file-io, base64, byte, bufferedimage

I have a website with an ongoing webcam stream which should send snapshots of the video stream to my own **Java webserver**. The snapshot generating and displaying functionality works perfectly on the website. I want to send the snapshot with a **jQuery AJAX POST** request to my webserver which looks like that:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: servicePath + "upload",
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: false},
    headers: {},
    data: hidden_canvas.toDataURL('image/png'),
    success: function(data, status, xhttp) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Error uploading snapshot file to server!");
    }
});
```

As I mentioned, displaying the `hidden_canvas.toDataURL('image/png')` inserted in a `src` attribute of an `<img>` works perfectly, so it is definitely valid.

My **service** on the webserver looks as follows:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadPicture(byte[] imageBytes) {

    String uploadedFileLocation = UPLOAD_FOLDER + "test.png";

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        out.write(imageBytes);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {       
        return Response.status(500).entity("Can not save file<br>" + e.toString()).build();
    }

    return Response.status(200).entity("success").build();
}
```

`Test.png` is created successfully but not a valid `png`, when I open it, it does not display at all. And the file on the server looks as follows:
[image: Test.png content]

What did I miss? Would there be an alternative way to process the image?

---

Here's my `takeSnapshot` method. How could I send the file without the `toDataURL()`? And what for param would I have to expect then on the server side?

```
function generateSnapshot() {
   var video = document.querySelector('#camera-stream');
   var hidden_canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
   var context = hidden_canvas.getContext('2d');

   var width = video.videoWidth;
   var height = video.videoHeight;

   if (width && height) {
       hidden_canvas.width = width;
       hidden_canvas.height = height;

       // Make a copy of the current frame in the video on the canvas.
       context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

       // Turn the canvas image into a dataURL that can be used as a src for our photo.
       return hidden_canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you create `byteArrayString` then parse it back to `imageBytes`?

Comment: Because i wanted to get rid of the **"image/png;base64"** beginning, I read that this could lead to invalid files. It was a desperate try to make it somehow valid. But I was not able to `substring` it, due to the fact that `byteArrayString` seems to look totally different afterwards. Should the image be valid also with this prefix? And how could I convert it to such a valid file?

Comment: Converting bytes to base64 and back to bytes won't get rid of anything. Are you sending the image to the server as a data URL? Why? Why not send the bytes directly?

Comment: Ok, I see. Yes, I do, as data URL, I would not know how else. How could I send the bytes directly?

Comment: Probably with `toBlob()`. Then you don't need to worry about Base64, data URL prefixes or anything.

Comment: Ok, sounds promising, I'll try it!

Comment: @Kayaman I was not able to understand how and where exactly I should convert the file to a blob, I added my `generateSnapshot()` method. Could you make an example how to do it? And what would that mean for my service?

Comment: Using [toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) instead of `toDataURL` would give you the binary data instead of the Base64 encoded data URL. Then your service doesn't need to do much, since it's getting the correct data in the correct format.

Comment: @Kayaman Thank you very much for your patience. The `toBlob` suggestion really put me on the right track. I finally could make it work with some adjustments (_see answer_). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally could make it work. The `toBlob` suggestion from **[Kayaman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541560/kayaman)** put me on the right track. But I was not able to send the blob as expected, I had to put it into a `FormData` and thus had to adjust my webservice. The solution looks as follows:

Website **Javascript** code:

```
hidden_canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('fileName', 'testBlob.png');
    fd.append('data', blob);
    sendAJAXFileUploadRequest(fd);
},'image/png');

function sendAJAXFileUploadRequest(formData) {
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: servicePath + "upload",
       xhrFields: {withCredentials: false},
       headers: {},
       data: formData,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       success: function(data, status, xhttp) {
           alert(data);
       },
       error: function() {
           alert("Error uploading snapshot file to server!");
       }
   });          
}
```

And the **Java Webservice**:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadPicture(@FormDataParam("data") byte[] imageBytes, @FormDataParam("fileName") String fileName) {

    String uploadedFileLocation = UPLOAD_FOLDER + fileName;

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        out.write(imageBytes);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {       
        logger.severe("Can not save file (file location: " + uploadedFileLocation + ")");
        return Response.status(500).entity("Can not save file<br>" + e.toString()).build();
    }

    return Response.status(200).entity("success").build();
}
```